# Use a in FoxPro written DLL in a C# windows-forms-application

Tags: c#, dll, visual-foxpro

I have a `single-threaded COM DLL` built and written in `VisualFoxPro` and I'd like to use the procedures from the dll in a `C#` win-forms-application.

Now it ain't a problem to add a reference to the DLL, but if I want to use the DLL like I usually do it by

```
using System;
```

etc, the newly referenced DLL won't show up.

Is there a possibility to properly reference or include a VFP-written DLL?

And to call the procedures from it then?

Or do I need to import the DLL from my project, reference it from there and do I need to change something in my VS then?

Sadly my research didn't bring any results, only the reverse way, which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use such library as [managed code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) but you can use unmanaged code with nteroperability.

First, read about some [interoperability basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx), then take a look at some of examples of using FoxPro libraries

- [example
  one](https://west-wind.com/presentations/VfpDotNetInterop/DotNetFromVFP.asp)
- [second example](http://www.codemag.com/article/0404072)

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood me. I wrote a DLL in FoxPro and want to use that one in a C# application which I will write soon. Your Examples are just reversed to what I search for.

Comment: second link contains both ways - using FoxPro dll from c# and vice versa

Comment: @DatRid, I skipped commenting before because Nino already gave the answer. Looks like you failed to create olepublic in the first place. Create olepublic classes and then simply use tlbimp.exe to make your dll to be usable from .Net. But, if you ask me, FWIW do not create and use a VFP dll from .Net, instead write your code in C# (at least that was the lesson I learned the hard way).

Answer (score 2):

Going back a few years, and from what I remember, if the reference is good, you need to create an INSTANCE of the object that was made as OlePublic in your VFP compiled dll.  Then, from that object instance you should be able to access and call your exposed functions and procedures.  Try that first and I will try to see what I can dig-up.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try that out. (Only classes are OlePublic definable?) No need to hurry, I won't be able to give you more feedback today sadly, but I will come back to that tomorrow!

Comment: @DatRid, Check the link from Nino's second example.  The team from Code magazine were well versed from the VFP world and show sample code of OlePublic creation of a class and making available to be used on the web.  The basics are the same.  One class, made as OlePublic then you can expose from that.   Let me know what progress you make tomorrow from that and if need be, will try to get more specific examples... Maybe via chat or direct email.